# Electron file path in package issue

Tags: node.js, file, path, electron

I wonder how to get the correct path to file what should be loaded by fs.readFile:
File to load is in the app's root directory.

Starting the app in cli with npm start

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('settings.json');
```

works

After packing and starting electron.exe it will lead to 
'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory'

I can fix this for the packaged app with loading by

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(process.resourcesPath,  'app', 'settings.json'));
```

but then the file isn't found runing the app by npm start.

What is the correct way to determine the path to a file in any environement?

Comment: I've had success using `__dirname` - see my question about paths here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775790/which-context-is-the-path-relative-to

Comment: Yes, I tried this first and it failed. Now I changed all path's to __dirname and now it works, dunno know what my mistake was. Possible that there is a kind of caching? Thanks.